# Name of a specific type of texture

Tags: texture

In this [website](http://everydayicons.jp/), there is this texture...
[image: everydayicons.com]

Can you tell me the name of this texture and if there is an online generator?

Comment: Stucco perhaps? It was the first that came to my mind at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop....

Filter > Texture > Texturize...

Burlap.

[image: burlap]

And then there's another texture applied on top of it maybe.